# What is or how to choose,calculate the optimal query point for Logistic regression with RBF kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, data-mining, kernel-trick

I have implemented a Logistic Regression with RBF kernel. I have trained the algorithm using a **training set** and a **query point** after the **weights** have been calculated i applied this **weights** to the **test set**.

**The problem** is that I reached **different accuracy levels** on the **test set** between 55%-90% depending on what **query point** I have chosen.

So what is the way to find or choose the best **query point**?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a classification problem, and by "query point", you mean the cutoff value of the Logistic Regression that you use to classify as Positive or Negative? If so, you choose your cutoff based on what metric of is important to you. It may be Accuracy, Precision, Recall, etc. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix for more information on a Confusion Matrix and various metrics you might use.)

For example, an investigative organization might care a lot about the False Positive Rate, because their most valuable resource is investigator hours.

(If you're really going to do it properly, you need to account for the losses or costs associated with each quadrant of the confusion matrix.)